# Access to remote machines via Terminal. Power Shell

Tags: powershell, command-line, terminal, remote-access

I have some machines with Windows and with installed VNC.
I can connect to them from my local computer via UltraVNC.
But now I need to connect to those machines via some terminal. Command line, or Windows Power Shell.
All I know are IPs and password to connect via UltrVNC.
Do you have aby idea if it is even possible and if yes, how to do that?

I have o lot of that machines and need to write some script to chec some files on them.

Comment: Your question is a bit off topic for this site. Anyways, couple of ways you can do this. Would recommend googling, or using the search function here to look for "PowerShell remoting".

Answer (score 0):

If you **only** have VNC access, then you may be able to use the [vncdotool](https://github.com/sibson/vncdotool) python module to basically emulate mouse+kb control over VNC.

---

Here are the other (built-in) console methods for windows remote access, using powershell for example:

- **WinRM:** For opening a full remote session: `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName myServer`
- **WMI** (DCOM/RPC): For querying any system information, and limited remote ability to run commands/start processes: `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName myServer`
- **RPC:** More limited, lightweight way to remotely call specific functions/procedures: `Get-Service spooler -ComputerName myServer | Restart-Service`

Or other services that can be installed like SSH/SFTP/FTP.